# Cannot change to front copper layer in KiCAD

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers, kicad, copper-pour

I am learning to design PCB using KiCAD. I followed a tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eulAvdYqYGg).  I got stuck at changing the layer of the PCB. From the video, the layers can be interchange by pressing page up (front copper) or page down (back copper). My filled zone layer is b.cu and net is GND. The B.Cu layer is just fine but when i change to F.Cu layer, it is still the same as before.

I have inserted a picture showing my issue. As you can see the selected layer is F.Cu but it is showing the back side. What have I done wrong and how can I change to front layer?

[image]

Comment: Are you only interested in seeing the front side ATM? In that case, Untick everything that shows stuff from backside.

Comment: Untick stuff from backside makes the green back copper layer disappear. It works. But isn't it a hassle to do that everytime? Using page up or page down is faster to switch between layers and check the connection

Comment: Page up and Page down if for selecting copper layer.

Comment: That does apply to the pin of SMD components as well? If you look at the video around 11:38 to 11:41, you can see the pin of the SMD becomes very visible after selecting the front copper layer

Comment: Haven't seen the video, will check out and get back

Comment: I haven't used KiCad for some time, but I expect that "page-up/page-down" changes the working layer - where any tracks you draw will be placed - not the visible layers.  I normally want both layers shown while laying out a board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I do the copper pour after routing is done. But any way, you can untick B.Cu layer to hide the bottom layer. Also you can click on "Do not show filled areas in zone" on the left side toolbar(11th button from top), to hide the copper pour. Doing this is a must when routing on bottom layer, as you will not be able to see the tracks as lay them down and you will need to rebuild the copper pour every time after the wire is connected by pressing 'b'.

Another thing, in the tutorial, he is using openGL mode while routing, and from the screenshot its seems you are in default mode. To switch to openGL mode go to View>Switch to OpenGL or press 'F11' key.

Comment: That is the answer. I am unaware of the openGL mode. Entering that mode is what I wanted to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the preview for things that you don't want to see from the backside.
It basically shows you front and back part of PCB in same screen. You need to chose what you want to see.

Comment: I have untick B.Mask, but nothing change when I press page up and page down. It is still the same as before. The front layer is still hidden behind

Comment: You need to untick B.cu @iHateUni

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in a few nightly builds that makes copper rendering opaque, and then saves that as new default.

You can correct that by double-clicking the color swatch next to the layer name and reducing opacity to a sensible value. We use 60% by default.